Calculation of effect size, statistical power, and confidence interval for different statistical tests
Introduction.
I am studying the number of ants which go to their ant nest, every minute, from different areas around the ant nest. I also know an approximate distance that those ants travel to reach the ant nest.
About the spatial information, I can say that the area around the ant nest is split into grid's cells, and the ant nest lies at the center of the grid.
About the temporal information, I can say that the overall time window of this study is 10 hours (actually more, but I try to make my example easy to grasp). I split the 10 hours of observations into 10 single periods of observation - equivalent to say that I have 10 experiments -, each one lasting 60 minutes.
Examples of observed data.
During the first observation period, i.e. during the first hour, I know that:

at minute 1, we observe  7 ants reaching the nest from different grid's cells (around the nest)
at minute 2, we observe 24 ants reaching the nest from different grid's cells (around the nest)
at minute 3, we observe 19 ants reaching the nest from different grid's cells (around the nest)
and so on, up to minute 59

The number of ants is an integer, while the distances they travel are decimal numbers (like 4.80 meters, or 10.30 meters).
If we derive the histograms/distributions of those data, we can get something like this (please note that the plots are completely made up) both for the number of ants that, every minute reach their nest, and for their distance travelled:

By eye, we can notice that the resulting distributions (related to the 10 different periods of observations, i.e. during hour 1, during hour 2, etc..) are non-normal, and they are quite overlapping.
Here, the null hypothesis $H_0$ would be:

About the number of ants which reach their nest, the corresponding 10 distributions are very similar, almost overlapping,
About the distances travelled to reach their nest, the corresponding 10 distributions are very similar, almost overlapping.

On the other side, the alternative hypothesis $H_1$ would be:

About the number of ants which reach their nest, the corresponding 10 distributions are very different,
About the distances travelled to reach their nest, the corresponding 10 distributions are very different.

My questions.
Now, I would like to test those hypotheses, by using the following two-sample tests to compare my non-normal distributions:

Chi-square test
Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
Wilcoxon rank sum test
Kruskal-Wallis test

All of them return a p-value, i.e. a p-value for the Chi-square test, a p-value for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, a p-value for the Wilcoxon rank sum test, and a p-value for the Kruskal-Wallis test.
Since the p-value is not enough to understand the data/distributions (for example, please see Sullivan & Feinn (2012), Dunkler et al.(2020), Greenland (2016), and du Prel et al. (2009)), I would like to calculate

the effect size,
the statistical power of the test, and
the confidence interval (of hypothesis testing).

However, something is not clear.
Could you please tell me if all the additional (to the p-value) measures, i.e. (i) the effect size, (ii) the statistical power of the test, and (iii) the confidence interval (of hypothesis testing), need to be calculated for each of the statistical tests, (i.e. Chi-square test, Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, Wilcoxon rank sum test, and Kruskal-Wallis test), or they do not depend on the statistical test and can be calculated only once?
Also, if all the additional (to the p-value) measures, i.e. (i) the effect size, (ii) the statistical power of the test, and (iii) the confidence interval (of hypothesis testing), need to be calculated for each of the statistical tests, should I adapt the equations related to effect size, statistical power, and confidence interval to each type of statistical test?

Why do you want to calculate power after conducting a test? Power analysis is relevant to find the required sample size before collecting the data, not after collecting the data and conducting a test. See https://library.virginia.edu/data/articles/post-hoc-power-calculations-are-not-useful for example.

In addition, even for a single test like the chi-squared test, different effect sizes exist (Cohen's w, Cramér's V, Tschuprow's T, odds ratio, etc.). It would be helpful to give more context (why are you asking this question?), and explain the research question you're trying to answer. You can edit your question to add all this information.

Also, note that if you are using different tests on the same data, it's hinting to something you're doing wrong (see "data dredging"), so you should definitely give much more details about the context of your question so we can give you advice on what to do.

Reinforcing what @J-J-J said in comments, you are more likely to get useful help on this site if you edit your question to explain the substantive question that you are addressing and the hypothesis you are testing with your two-sample comparison. It's generally best to choose the type of test based on the nature of the data. Trying different tests and choosing the one that seems to work "best" on your data is likely to lead you astray. Please add that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

if I edit the question, could it be re-opened?

If you edit the question and make changes, you'll see there's an option to tick to make it a candidate to re-opening. Then, if a moderator or three experienced users approve it, it will be re-opened. It can take some time for it to be reviewed (as reviewers are volunteers, and there are other questions to review), but generally I'd say it takes from a couple of hours to one day, perhaps two.

In other words, the closure of a question is not definitive if you edit it to make appropriate changes. The purpose of requiring more details before re-opening the question is to avoid answers that do not address the real problem you have, or that could lead you on a wrong track.

Thanks a lot, I edited my question, explaining all the background. I hope it is clear now!

Hi to everyone! Any suggestion about my questions? :-)

First, it might not be a good idea to perform multiple types of tests. That can lead to questions about which test to rely on if the results differ. If they do differ, there might be further questions of whether you are choosing the particular test that gave you results you might have been hoping for. Choose a test that is most appropriate to your type of data and subject matter.
This page discusses a couple of more tests beyond the ones you listed that you might want to consider for pairwise comparisons: the Anderson-Darling test and the Cramér-von Mises test.
These tests evaluate different aspects of (dis)similarity and thus of the corresponding "effect size." You might choose in part based on which aspect of (dis)similarity is most important to you and your audience.
For example, the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is on the maximum distance between the two cumulative distribution functions. Mann-Whitney and Kruskal-Wallis are tests of stochastic dominance: whether a random choice from one distribution is likely to be higher than that from another. Anderson-Darling and Cramér-von Mises tests are based on weighted squared differences between the cumulative distributions, with Anderson-Darling putting more weight on the extremes. Chi-square tests are on whether there are differences among frequencies in categories; that might not be a good choice when you have essentially continuous data, as you then need to arbitrarily place the data into bins.
Which of those types of (dis)similarity do you care about and want to explain to your audience? Choose a test accordingly.
Second, if each of your null hypotheses is that "the corresponding 10 distributions are very similar, almost overlapping," you might choose a test that evaluates all 10 distributions at once. This page discusses some multiple-sample tests and implementations; Kruskal-Wallis could be added. One choice is to do all 45 pairwise tests of your chosen type among the 10 distributions and correct for multiple comparisons. Kruskal-Wallis and Anderson-Darling tests have ready implementations of multiple-sample versions (there are multiple-sample versions of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test but I'm not familar with them). If a multiple-sample test does show differences, you will need to go back to pairwise tests to determine which differ, anyway.
Third, you are correct that relying on p-values alone is unwise, as explained in the references you cite. If you have already collected the data, however, then there is no sense in performing a power calculation. See this answer for the general principles arguing against such "post-hoc power tests" and this page for arguments more specific to tests like Kolmogorov-Smirnov.
Fourth, there are many types of "effect size". It would seem that the most relevant "effect size" for this study would be the measure of dissimilarity provided by your test. I'm not sure whether these tests provide confidence intervals; those would be in terms of that measure of dissimilarity.
Fifth, with this many observations it's quite possible that you will find some "statistically significant" differences. The question will be whether any such differences among the distributions are significant in practice. You will need to apply your understanding of the subject matter to answer that.
Finally, it seems that your fundamental questions are (1) whether arrival rates of ants at the nest differ as a function of time over a 10-hour period and (2) whether the distances traveled by ants returning to the nests differ in that respect. As you seem to have information collected every minute, you might be better off not breaking down the observations into hours. Instead, keep the data per minute and examine directly the associations with time as a flexibly modeled continuous predictor, for example with regression splines. There are statistical models designed for counts/rates (Poisson, quasi-Poisson, negative binomial) and semiparametric models for more continuous measures (like the distances) that don't depend on the assumptions of ordinary least-squares regression. Such models could tell you, much more directly than these tests on distributions, how much return rates and distances traveled by ants change over time.

Thanks a lot @EdM! An awesome answer, I am really thankful!!!

A very silly doubt... The Anderson-Darling test should be distribution-free, and I can take any empirical distributions as the two samples. However, I do not understand if the Cramér-von Mises is distribution-free as well? Indeed, in my case, I would need distribution-free tests.. :-)

@Ommo the two-sample test (which you would use in your application) for either of those is distribution-free, comparing two empirical distributions. What might be confusing you is that each can also be used in a one-sample test, of a single sample against a specified distribution.

Ah ok, thanks a lot, I was thinking exactly about the same! Doubt cleared, many thanks :-)
